# how can i know in which state a server is located?

Tags: web, location

i working on a project which compare between load time of websites on different server around the world.

in my project i need to buy a spot for a website in several servers but i don't know in which country the server is actually located.
i found an add-on in firefox called "flagfox" (i'm not related to the program, to check it visit: http://flagfox.net/) which indicate in which country the site is located.

i want to know:
a) how can "flagfox" know in which country the site is located? (in is not by the extention e.g .com .uk)
b) how can i know where in the country itself the site is located, i.e in the u.s.a is not very helpful because the server can be in new-york or in los angeles which are several time zones apart.
c) if i don't know the answer to a, how can i verify that the data from "flagfox" or other software for that matter, is reliable?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Flagfox site:

> It works by accessing an internal IP
>   address location database, basically a
>   rough map of the physical layout of
>   the Internet, based on data provided
>   by Maxmind.

You can get access to the maxmind dataset at http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article about this [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4549/extracting-the-country-from-the-ip-address-how-to/), complete with sample code. It references a database that is [available here](http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/).

The database can also be obtained [here](http://software77.net/geo-ip/).